# I am getting an error on line 13. It says that the `<<` method is undefined. how do I fix this? I am using Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

This is the code:

```
  def self.scrape_shoe
    @doc.css("div.product-card__body").each do |nike|
      name = nike.css("div.product-card__title").text.strip
      price = nike.css("div.product-card__price").text.strip
      shoes = self.new
      @all << shoes #having error here
    end 
  end
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        7: from bin/new_nikes:7:in `<main>'
        6: from /home/merkonical/new_nikes/lib/new_nikes/cli.rb:17:in `call'
        5: from /home/merkonical/new_nikes/lib/new_nikes/cli.rb:11:in `list_price'
        4: from /home/merkonical/new_nikes/lib/new_nikes/scraper.rb:9:in `scrape_shoe'
        3: from /home/merkonical/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `each'
        2: from /home/merkonical/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `upto'
        1: from /home/merkonical/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:238:in `block in each'
/home/merkonical/new_nikes/lib/new_nikes/scraper.rb:13:in `block in scrape_shoe': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

What are possible fixes I can do for this?
I am working on Ruby

Answer (score 1):

> What are possible fixes I can do for this?

`@all` is `nil`. `nil` doesn't have a method named `<<`. Make sure `@all` is not `nil`.

Comment: This question might be too broad but what are common things causes it to be nil?

Comment: There are exactly two possible reasons: you assigned `nil` to the variable or you didn't assign anything to the variable.

Comment: you could set `@all ||= []` before the `@doc.css`

Answer (score 0):

Getting error because you are pushing `shoes`  object into undefined instance variable.

Define `@all` in action.

```
def self.scrape_shoe 
  @doc.css("div.product-card__body").each do |nike|
      @all = []
      name = nike.css("div.product-card__title").text.strip
      price = nike.css("div.product-card__price").text.strip
      shoes = self.new
      @all << shoes #having error here
    end 
  end
```

Hope this helps you